# Incredible2 and Gmail notifications

Tags: notifications, audio, gmail, htc-droid-incredible-2

My wife has an HTC Droid Incredible 2, unrooted, running Android 2.3.4, HTC Sense 2.1.  If she  gets a Gmail email, the notification appears in the notification bar AND it plays a notification sound.

What I'd like to do is to get the notification in the bar, but not hear the sound.  Gmail now only displays an option to display a notification or not.  There are no settings for notification sound in Gmail.  But the phone's notification sound can be changed, but there is no "Silent" ringtone.  You can add ringtones for the phone ringer, but those added ringtones don't appear in the notification sound list.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gmail app now does notifications based on “labels” instead of having global notification settings. That way you can have different settings per label.  So, if you go to the inbox label (I think), you can set the sound there…